# How to create a 2D table in excel using Pivot table or formulas where the result cells are not containing only values but characters as well?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

Consider the below table which has the office and home cities of 3 people mentioned.

Input Table

[image: Input Table].

I need to create a 2D table which looks like below.

Output Table

[image: Output Table].

I tried using Pivot table but it only displays count or distinct count and not the exact value from the cell.

Suggest me a formula or VB code to do this as I need this a lot and if i have a structure, I can replicate this for every excel file and save a lot of time. My excels have hundreds of cells and it gets complicated to do manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Many ways to do this, perhaps for readability & simplicity one could use `PIVOTBY()` provided using **MS365** <sup>**Beta**</sup> Version enabled.*

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E1</kbd>

```
=PIVOTBY(A2:A7,C2:C7,B2:B7,ARRAYTOTEXT,,0,,0)
```

---

Or, Using `LAMBDA()` helper function called `MAKEARRAY()` to create the desired data structure.

```
=LET(
     _Names, A2:A7,
     _Location, B2:B7,
     _LDetails, C2:C7,
     _uniqueNames, UNIQUE(_Names),
     _uniqueLDetails, TOROW(UNIQUE(_LDetails)),
     _rows, ROWS(_uniqueNames),
     _columns, COLUMNS(_uniqueLDetails),
     _databody, MAKEARRAY(_rows,_columns,LAMBDA(r,c,IFERROR(FILTER(_Location,(INDEX(_uniqueNames,r)=_Names)*(INDEX(_uniqueLDetails,c)=_LDetails),""),""))),
     _headers, HSTACK("Names",_uniqueLDetails),
     VSTACK(_headers,HSTACK(_uniqueNames,_databody)))
```

---

`Power Query`, available in `Windows Excel 2010+` and `Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)`*.

[image]

---

To use Power Query follow the steps:

- First convert the source ranges into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table1`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Source, List.Distinct(Source[#"Location Details"]), "Location Details", "Location")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---